# Transfer Attribute doesn't work for nearest instance? [Confirmed 3.3 bug, asking for workarounds]

Tags: geometry-nodes, error

I minimized the problem to this form:

[image]

I'd expect the only instance to be found, and the attribute to be transferred… Switching the mode to *Index* passes the integer. No error icon is displayed on the node…

If I'm not doing anything wrong here and it's just the current limitation, what workarounds do you propose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug (missing feature) in Blender versions lower than **3.4**, which is now considered solved.

The current solution for 3.4 looks like this:

[image]

---

**Update**

Either I am completely wrong now, or it should actually also work without problems with version 3.3.

At least the following example correctly transfers the index of the instances to the other geometry:

[image]

...please don't hit me right away, if I still haven't completely understood the question ;-)

Comment: Since 3.3 is LTS, I'd think they should fix it there too… 

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Hm, you're right, but I'm afraid that might be difficult, since with 3.4 some changes have been added that are not backward compatible as far as I know.

Comment: Now I'm foxed.(Please shoot this down.)  _Sample Nearest_ 's target is an unrealized instance, which has no points. So it always returns 0. (You get lucky sampling index at index 0, because that's the only one.) If I try this with a grid of instances, it's essentially non-functional?

Comment: @RobinBetts ...you may be right: something is wrong here. Thinking error? I'll have to take a closer look.

Comment: @RobinBetts There was one node missing, I think ;-)

Comment: @RobinBetts Please try this file: https://blend-exchange.com/b/G3zGLjYA/

Comment: @q  Ahh! That's better. Thanks for having a look! It's a shame IMO that an instance is not considered to _be_ a point, (with  a  transform matrix). Then you wouldn't have to convert it explicitly. I don't think that would break the grammar..

Comment: I didn't want to be pedantic and say that while the question reproduces the problem in the simplest form, perhaps an answer should work on more than one point, like in my answer. And I didn't test the solution, because well, it's quellenform, the only guy with gold geonodes badge :D. That and I don't use alpha versions for sanity.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I'm right there with you, I also build now and then quite a bit of crap or I make mistakes. But please do not hold back, I appreciate your criticism and comments very much! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

My current workaround is to scale the instances to 0, capture their positions, space them to make sure they don't overlap, realize them and merge by distance, restore positions and then sample the resulting vertices...

[image]

[image]

Edit: Just realized, the *Distance* in *Merge by Distance* should definitely be larger than $0.001/1000$ due to how the positions lose precision fast as you go away from 0. Since I set the offsets to $1$ on each axis, the distances turn out to be:

$$\sqrt{\sqrt{1^2 + 1^2}^2 + 1^2} = \sqrt{2 + 1} ≈ 1.73$$

So I changed the distance to $1$ m, which should be safe for a small number ($<16777218$) of instances, otherwise probably should use modulo to position on X, Y, Z separately to fully take advantage of float precision…

[image]